# Stack around the variable 'st' was corupted

Tags: c++, pointers, file-read

This is my code to bind a text file content to a linked list in C, the read job is ok but its made an error in fclose(f), Stack around the variable 'st' was corrupted. I don't understand it, how can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Nut
{
    char Tu[7];
    Nut * Tiep;
};


Nut TD[26];
Nut *first;

void AddFirst(Nut *q, Nut *&first)
{
    Nut *p;
    p = new Nut;
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = q;
        return;
    }
    for (p = first; p->Tiep != NULL; p = p->Tiep)
        p->Tiep = q;
}

void ReadData(Nut *ds[], int &n)
{
    n = 0;
    char old = '0';
    FILE *f;
    Nut *Tam;
    Nut *Tu;
    f = fopen("TD.txt", "r");

    int dem = -1;
    if (f == NULL)
        cout << "File rong !!!";
    else
    {
        while (!feof(f) == 1)
        {
            char st[8] = "";
            fscanf(f, "%s", st);
            Tam = new Nut();
            strcpy(Tam->Tu, st);
            char c = st[0];
            if (c != old){
                dem++;
                ds[dem] = new Nut();
                n++;
            }
            AddFirst(Tam, ds[dem]);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Update 1:
Sorry, I must do it in C, but I use Visual C++, the final environment is C
data file, td.txt

```
ACCEPT
ADULT
APART
AUGUST
BACK
BAD
BOY
BREAK
CAT
CHEF
CHICKEN
COWBOY
CRY
DAD
DESIGN
DIE
DRAW
EAT
EMPTY
ERROR
EXPLORE
FAN
FELL
FESTIVAL
FULL
GAS
GIVE
GRAPHIC
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings and I/O in C++? Somewhere you are clobbering memory that is out of bounds. A `std::string` might help with that.

Comment: To start with, don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect since the `EOF` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. You loop will iterate once to many.

Comment: aren't you supposed to use pointers in strcpy? surely it is...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm

Comment: And please provide a sample of the input file. And have you checked that there are no strings longer than 6 characters?

Comment: Joachim, so how can I fix it? Is while (fscanf(f, "%s", st) == 1) right answer?

Comment: Added td.txt data file

Answer (score 1):

You use `fscanf` to read the strings into an array containing 8 characters, which means you can read string having 7 characters at most because the last character must be the special string-termination character `'\0'`.

However, in the input you have e.g. the string

```
FESTIVAL
```

which is exactly 8 characters, but needs *9* characters including the terminator. This will cause `fscanf` to write beyond the bounds of the array `st`.

What's worse is that you then copy this 9-character data into an array of only 7 characters, once again writing out of bounds.

Writing out of bounds of an array leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and makes your whole program ill-formed.

Comment: OK, it's right, thank. I changed the st size to 9 and everything work well. The error message it not very easy to understand and fix :) Thank again

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem: you're reading into a buffer of
8 `char`, but some of your data requires 9 (don't forget the trailing
`'\0'`); you then `strcpy` this into a buffer of 7 `char`.  For the
input you give, you need buffers of at least 9 characters.  You also
want to provide a width argument in the format of `fscanf`, in order to
avoid overwriting the buffer regardless of the input.  (In fact, you
probably want to use `fgets`, to read line by line, with a very large
buffer, and then check that 1) you've actually read to the end of the
line (the last character should be a `'\n'`), and 2) that the word in
the line has at most one less characters than the size of your buffer.

(Obviously, this would all be significantly simpler in C++.)